# Facebook SDK share with text and a variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, facebook, share

This is my first time using the Facebook SDK and I am finding it a rather large and difficult to navigate source.

I have my app ID and I am ready to go. I can get a share button to come up and open correctly (though, weirdly, I can not get the button to show in a Bootstrap modal footer, if you can solve that too, I'd be grateful). But now with the share I want to say something like:
"I scored " [the variable "score"] at [website]"."

Then they can push "share".

I have this div `<div id="fb-root"></div>` - where should this be placed?

I have taken the information and source code from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

In summary: I'd like the FB share button to be able to be seen only in the modal footer (I can't seem to get this to work at all) and to have a small quote of text with the user's score.

Comment: You can not specify any custom quote with the share button. The share _dialog_ allows you to suggest a quote - but the user will be able to remove or modify that.

Comment: haha... I was literally reading that just as you posted. *sigh* Oh well... 

Would I be able to use the share dialogue to share a variable output?

Comment: You would be able to do what I just said, nothing more.

Comment: I have to say after lots of trial and error, I couldn't get quotes or anything to work. It just shares my page and that's it. Not that this is an issue. I'd just love them to be able to share a result they got from a test that was run or from a game they played on the site.

Comment: haha... on saying that I had an idea... I guess it is possible: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/sharing/#linkshares - will require some in-depth looking into.